# NightWatch.js - get a list of child WebElements based on relative css locator

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, pageobjects, nightwatch.js

Hello all NightWatch adopters,

I am trying to parse a table with the following format to get a a list of rows and the cell in each rows

```
<tbody> 
  <tr> // 1 row
    <td>Item A</td> // name
    <td>John</td> // owner
    <td>Monday</td> // create date
  </tr>
  <tr> // 2 row
    <td>Item B</td>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The code now looks like this which calls the function below.

```
browser.elements('css selector', 'tbody tr', getResultsList);
```

Where my function for parsing now looks like this.

```
function getResultsList(rowResults){
    // Here we get the correct set of rows 
    console.log(rowResults.length + ' rows found'); // this returns 2


    // Main loop going through the rows
    for(var i = 0; i < rowResults.value.length; i++) {
        var row = rowResults.value[i];
        console.log(row.value + ' -- row item');
        // need to get the <td> inside row
    }
}
```

In Java webdriver we can just do the following

```
List<WebElements> rows = driver.getElements("tbody tr");
    for (WebElement row : rows) {
        row.getElement(' > td:nth-child(1)') // name
        row.getElement(' > td:nth-child(2)') // creator
        row.getElement(' > td:nth-child(3)') // date
    }
```

I wanted to know if there is any straight forward way to do this in NightWatchJS similar how we do this in Java via child WebElement where we can just call `startingWebElement.getElement(childlocator);` without having to start all the way from the top and dynamically build/chain the locators e.g.

```
// name
browser.getText('css selector', 'tbody tr:nth-child('+i+') td:nth-child(1)')
// creator
browser.getText('css selector', 'tbody tr:nth-child('+i+') td:nth-child(2)')
// date
browser.getText('css selector', 'tbody tr:nth-child('+i+') td:nth-child(4)')
```

Any comments, suggestions, concerns, tips is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution yet? I am also looking for a convenient nighwatchjs way to find out how many table cells in my row are present before iterating through them

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to this problem...

Answer (score 2):

See if this works for you:

```
Page.getTableRows((rows) => {  
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    client.elementIdElements(row.ELEMENT, 'tag name', 'td', (result) => {
      console.log(`row td length ${result.value.length}`);
      result.value.forEach((cell) => {
        client.elementIdText(cell.ELEMENT, (text) => {
          console.log(`cell text ${text.value}`);
        })
      });
    });
  });
});`
```

Implementation of getTableRows

```
getTableRows(callback) {
  this.api.elements('css selector', \`${this.elements.table.selector} tbody tr\`, (data) => {

    if(data.state === 'success'){
      callback.call(this, data.value);
    }
  });
},
```